# iMessage Sync - Inconsistent?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, messages

I have iMessage installed on my iPhone and both of my macs - but when I've read a message on my iPhone, it remains unread on both macs - although this does not happen the other way around. I get quite a few messages and its getting tiresome going through telling it I've read them - is there any way to force a sync between all the machines?

Comment: It's in Beta for a reason, it's not 100% baked.  I would wait for the V1.0 release before asking such questions.

Comment: Excellent point. I'll vote my post for closure.

Comment: We kind semi-officially included messages as ontopic despite being beta, so the question is valid, I just don't think you will get any sensible answers just yet.